# Resplit long strings in TSQL

Tags: t-sql, split

I have a table with long strings splitted by 200char per row.
Now I need to re-split them with max 80char per row, is it possibile to do it with a TSQL function or I have to write and external program?

This is an example (text field lenght is reduced then I will have more rows per Id)

```
+----+----------------------------+
| Id | TextLong                   |
+----+----------------------------+
| 1  | Long text chunked part 1/3 |
+----+----------------------------+
| 1  | Long text chunked part 2/3 |
+----+----------------------------+
| 1  | Long text chunked part 3/3 |
+----+----------------------------+
| 2  | Long text chunked part 1/2 |
+----+----------------------------+
| 2  | Long text chunked part 2/2 |
+----+----------------------------+
```

To

```
+----+------------------------+
| Id | TextSmall              |
+----+------------------------+
| 1  | Long text chunked      |
+----+------------------------+
| 1  |  part 1/3Long text     |
+----+------------------------+
| 1  | chunked part 2/3 Long  |
+----+------------------------+
| 1  |  text chunked part 3/3 |
+----+------------------------+
| 2  | Long text chunked      |
+----+------------------------+
| 2  | part 1/2 Long text     |
+----+------------------------+
| 2  | chunked part 2/2       |
+----+------------------------+
```

Comment: Google how to turn a bunch of rows with 1 or 2 columns into 1 row with multiple columns, concat them into one long string, then split using your new requirement.

Comment: I would question the need to split the data at a database level. My preference would be to store the data in the table as full-length strings, then split the values when presenting the data (ex. to a UI). Why do you think you need to split the values into multiple rows in a database table?

Comment: @Brian this is for data migration between two database. First one has a "note" field size different from the second one. I did not decide the table structure, that was given by software house.

Comment: @Tobia maybe this can do with a stored procedure, but i do not think that could be done with a function. If the stored procedure will be useful for you, I could pass one.

Comment: I made a table-returning function, and it is working

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[resplit] ( @id int, @len int)
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE (id int IDENTITY(1,1), txt nvarchar(max))
AS
BEGIN

if @id is null
    return

 DECLARE @fulltxt nvarchar(max)=''
 DECLARE @rowList TABLE (id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, txt nvarchar(max), processed int default 0)
 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255), @value NVARCHAR(255), @tmp NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

insert into @rowList(txt) select LTRIM(RTRIM(nota)) from sourceTable where id=@id

if (Select Count(*) From @rowList) = 0
    return

While (Select Count(*) From @rowList Where Processed = 0) > 0
    Begin
        Select Top 1 @tmp = txt, @pos=id From @rowList Where Processed = 0 order by id
        set @fulltxt=@fulltxt+isnull(@tmp,'')
        Update @rowList Set processed = 1 Where id = @pos 
    End 

While len(@fulltxt)>0
    Begin
        set @pos=@len
        set @tmp = SUBSTRING(@fulltxt, 0, @pos)
        insert into @returnList(txt) select @tmp
        if len(@fulltxt)-@pos<=0
            set @fulltxt=''
        else
            set @fulltxt=SUBSTRING(@fulltxt, @pos+1, len(@fulltxt)-@pos)
    End 

RETURN
END
```

Short explanation:

- implode all rows into one string nvarchar(max)
- split this string into rows of defined size